# How to stop IIS 7.0 from redirecting to its own page when 403 error occurs

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7, asp.net-mvc-5, web-config

I am working on an asp.net mvc web application, and inside my application I have defined a custom authorization attribute , which will return 403 error if the user is not authorized as follow; and I provide two response types depending if the request is Ajax or not:-

```
 [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]

    public class CheckUserPermissionsAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {

        public string Model { get; set; }
        public string Action { get; set; }

        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            //code goes here .......
        }
        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {

            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                filterContext.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(403, "Sorry, you do not have the required permission to perform this action.");


            }
            else
            {
                var viewResult = new ViewResult();

                viewResult.ViewName = "~/Views/Errors/_Unauthorized.cshtml";
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 403;
                filterContext.Result = viewResult;
            }


        }
    }
```

The problem is that my current approach works fine on my development environment (not deployed to iis), but when I deploy my application to the staging server on IIS 7 ; then all my http requests (non-ajax) that have 403 error code will be redirect to the following page,

> 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied. You do not have permission to view
>   this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied

instead of redirecting to the custom page which I have created `~/Views/Errors/_Unauthorized.cshtml`, While if the request is Ajax it will show the jAlert box as defined inside my Ajax setup .

So I have the following two questions;

1. So can anyone advice how I can force my IIS not to redirect to its own page when 403 error is raised , and to redirect to the `~/Views/Errors/_Unauthorized.cshtml` view?
2. Second question, why my approach worked well if the request is an Ajax request, while it fails when the request is non-Ajax ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can define this is the application web.config in the `httpErrors` element.
Here is a link to the documentation:
http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httperrors

Basically you need to add this:

```
<httpErrors>
  <remove statusCode="403" subStatusCode="-1" />
  <error statusCode="403" path="[The path to custom page]" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply i added the following <httpErrors>
  <remove statusCode="403" subStatusCode="-1" />
  <error statusCode="403" path="~/Views/Errors/_Unauthorized.cshtml" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors> to the web.config , but the problem i am currently facing is that if an 403 error is raised , a white page will be displyed and when i check it using firebug it will raise 404 error , as if it is trying to reference something that does not exsits...

Comment: I think redirecting to a `CSHTML` file is not a good idea. I think you should create an Error controller and redirect to there. Also, make sure that the error controller itself is not secured and does not use any secure resources.

Comment: why it is not a good idea to redirect to custom page ? and is this the problem in my case ,  that i am calling the view directly ? and i should call an action method instead ? thnaks

Comment: The problem is not with redirecting to a custom page. The problem is that you are redirecting to a `CSHTML` file. This file could include server-side code, which is not run if not called through a controller. You can either call this view through a controller or just create a static `HTML` file and redirect to there.